# Function to retrieve requested url for passing to case statement

Tags: php

Is there a function I can use to extract a requested URL?

I want to evaluate the path in a case statement to import my views/includes/etc so if anyone can point me in the direction of something I would be really grateful.

i was going to use something like this...

```
function curPageURL() {

    //create url prefix ie https://...etc
    $pageURL = 'http';

    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on"){$pageURL .= "s";}

    $pageURL .= "://";

    //if not on port 80 find out which port were on
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {        
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];        
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
//return full url string
return $pageURL;
}

variable = curPageURL();
```

Comment: You should get used to indenting your code properly, especially when asking for help and expecting people to have to read it.

Comment: I generally do but was a tad rushed when I typed this earlier. Do you have any advice on the content of my question? Thanks

Comment: Lanzz I've made some adjustments for you however I would appreciate constructive comments, If you are unable to add anything positive please don't post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out.

If anyone has this idea just set a variable value and sent it accorss the URL, a la...

```
<li><a href="index.php?content=location">Locations</a></li>
```

then intercept that in a controller (via an include on the main template, I use my own MVC with a nav controller), like this....

```
if(isset ($_GET["content"])){   
    switch ($_GET["content"]){
        case 'home':
            $masterURL = 'views/contenthome.php';
            $div_id = "content_home";
        break;
        case 'courses':

            $masterURL = 'views/courses.php';
            $div_id = "content_courses";
        break;

    }//end switch
}else{
    $masterURL = 'views/contenthome.php';
}//end if
```

Its simple and effective but I hope it helps somebody somewhere.